# Migrate local profile to domain profile on same computer in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, domain, user-profiles

I have found variations on this, but not this specific one. I have had a local account on my laptop for some time, which has just been joined to the company domain. I am a local admin, but not a domain admin. I'd like to copy my local profile into the domain profile. (Not hack up the registry to point both accounts to the same directory)

Windows Easy Transfer requires me to be a domain admin. The 'registry profile list' method on Technet leaves you with one profile essentially, and also doesn't work for me (can't open ntuser.dat for the local profile). Is there another way, or a tool to do this?

Comment: Yes;  Have an Administrator on the domain do the transfer for you.  Any tool that has the capability to do this would require the capability to take ownership of the local user's profile folder which as a non-administrator on the Domain you don't have that capability.

Comment: I do have that capability though - in my initial fiddling, I've given my domain account full control on my local account's profile directory.

Comment: So just manually transfer the files to the same location.  That's all the `Windows East Transfer` does anyways.

Comment: OK - it doesn't do anything special with registry settings?

Comment: If it does then any tool that replicated the functionality would still need domain `Administrator` permissions.  I would ask a domain `Administrator` for assistance.